# WAS Liberty Profile connect to MQ Server

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty

We are experimenting with IBM's WebSphere Liberty profile. Now we have trouble to connect to our WebSphere MQ server. It works for normal WebSphere profile. We followed this tutorial https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/2013/06/14/using-websphere-mq-with-the-liberty-profile/ and I ran into the following Exception:

```
Stack Dump = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue
```

Any idea what I could change, so that this class could be found?

I am working with Liberty Profile, version 8.5.5.3.

my `server.xml` looks the following:

```
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>jsf-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>beanValidation-1.0</feature>
        <feature>wasJmsClient-1.1</feature>
        <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
        <feature>jmsMdb-3.1</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" />

    <application id="myapp" name="myApp" type="ear" location="d:\somehwere">
        <classloader delegation="parentLast" commonLibraryRef="global" />
    </application>

    <variable name="wmqJmsClient.rar.location" value="D:\opt\was_liberty_profile\was_8_5_5_3\wlp\usr\shared\wmq\wmq.jmsra.rar"/>

    <library id="global">
        <file name="d:/dev/mavenrepo/com/h2database/h2/1.4.181/h2-1.4.181.jar" />
    </library>

    <jmsQueue id="MYAPP_QUEUE" jndiName="jms/test/testq">
        <properties.wmqJms 
            baseQueueName="MYAPP.TEST.A" 
            persistence="PERS" 
            targetClient="MQ"/>
    </jmsQueue>

    <jmsQueueConnectionFactory id="TEST.SVRCONN.001" jndiName="jms/test/testcf"><!-- connectionManagerRef="ConMgr2">-->
     <properties.wmqJms 
        channel="WM026D.SVRCONN.001" 
        hostName="i19328.myhost.ch" 
        port="1439" 
        queueManager="WM026D" 
        targetClientMatching="false"/>
    </jmsQueueConnectionFactory>

    <jmsActivationSpec id="fvtapp/fvtmdb/FVTMessageDrivenBean">
  <properties.wmqJms destinationRef="MYAPP_QUEUE"
                     destinationType="javax.jms.Queue"
                     queueManager="WM026D"/>
</jmsActivationSpec>
</server>
```

Comment: Can you provide what you have in your server.xml? I assume you downloaded the wmq resource adapter as per the tutorial?

Comment: @whitfiea what do you mean with your second question? I think that my colleague downloaded from IBM

Comment: I meant that you downloaded the wmq.jmsra.rar as it does come as part of Liberty by default. As Gas already mentioned the problem is you have the wrong feature loaded, so the class you mentioned is not loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong feature there. It should be:

```
<feature>wmqJmsClient-1.1</feature>
```

not:

```
<feature>wasJmsClient-1.1</feature>
```

the later one is for built in messaging not MQ.

Comment: Thank you. That was the first part of the solution. Second part we "casted" the configured queue in web.xml to com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue. We changed it java.jms.Queue and now it runs.